# compare 2 tables if match update if not match insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables with same table structure. Table A is having all transaction with 3 unique key in each record. Table B have only condition base record only.

I want compare both tables if Table B has matching record than I want to update and Table B have not matching record than insert in Table B.

Can you please suggest best way to do it like ssis or any thing else

Comment: Can you please show us your table schema?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is a [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement:

```
MERGE INTO Table_B  
USING Table_A 
ON TableA.ID1 = Table_B.ID1 AND TableA.ID2 = Table_B.ID2 AND TableA.ID3 = Table_B.ID3
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET A = Table_A.A, B = Table_A.B         -- Etcetera...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (A, B) VALUES (Table_A.a, Table_A.B) -- Etcetera...
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE                            -- If Necessary...
;
```

By the way, don't forget the ";" at the end.  SQL Server doesn't usually need them, but a `MERGE` does.

Comment: If you post the schema of your tables, someone could give you a specific SQL Statement.

Comment: Can you please mark it as accepted answer by clicking on outlined checkmark to the left of the question.